# MVC pattern with Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a simple question. I am developing an Android application that uses as backend Firebase realtime database. I was wondering if can it be said that my app is built following the MVC pattern, although I do not have my own logic, my own server, I am using the API from Firebase. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use `MVC pattern with Firebase`. With Firebae it's even simpler. You can create a model class in which you can declare all the variables you need. This can include also other classes. Create all the constructors that you need. Add `public setters` and `public getters` and you'll have your complete model class or your `POJO`. Don't forget to add `the no argument constructor` needed for Firebase.

Here is an example of an user model class with only two fields.

```
public class UserModel implements Serializable {
    private String userEmail;
    private String userName;

    public UserModel() {}

    public void setUserEmail(String userEmail) {this.userEmail = userEmail;}
    public String getUserEmail() {return userEmail;}

    public void setUserName(String userName) {this.userName = userName;}
    public String getUserName() {return userName;}
}
```

Every change that is made in your Firebase database is triggerd in real time in your user interface.

I recomand you reading the `official documentation` for Firebase. [Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) is how to `add Firebase to your Android Project` and [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/) is how you can `set up Firebase Realtime Database for Android`. And [here](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android) is how you can use `FirebaseUI for Android`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Ok, thanks. This was really helpful. I already did this. Thank you :)

Comment: Try this out for not just mvc but also for mvp and mvvmon both java and kotlin. https://github.com/saksham24/Android-Firebase-Mvp-Mvc-Mvvm-chat

Comment: If that's the model, in order to retrieve data from Firebase should I separate it and put it in controllers?

Comment: @parkorian I'm not sure I understand. So please post a question, here on StackOverflow, using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.